# Dialogflow is accepting wrong date

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Whenever I enter 37th June as an input it doesn't give error rather it considers the date as 30th June. What I want to do is to create an error prompt whenever 37th June is entered.

I am using @sys.date on a very simple intent which does nothing but accepts date parameter.

Comment: its a bug in dialogflow, date validation should have been more accurate from their side. for now i think you should put your own logic in webhook to validate the date using `$date.original`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using dialogflow and the nodejs fulfillment you could include moment and do some date validation quickly on your own:

`moment(dateUserEnteredHere).isValid();`